# Django in production not showing custom 404 page

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

My django site is in production on digital ocean with Ubuntu 18.04 and Django 2.2. It is working with Nnginx and Gunicorn following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

I cannot get it to display my custom 404 page.

I have tried setting up the 404 by adding `handler404 ='forum.views.error_404'` in urls. I added the following view function.

```
def error_404(request):
        data = {}
        return render(request,'forum/error_404.html', data)
```

The rest of my Nginx setup is as shown in the tutorial. I think I have to change something in my config for Nginx for this to work, something about proxies, but I have no idea how to do it I am completely lost with those config files and which lines to add where.

This is the nginx config

```
server {
    server_name somesite.com www.somesite.com;
    client_max_body_size 15M;

    location /static {
        root /home/mike/myprojectdir/somesite22/newforum;
    }
     location /media/ {
        root /home/mike/myprojectdir/somesite22/newforum;
    }



 location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/somesite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed $
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/somesite.com/privkey.pem; # manage$
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {   
 if ($host = somesite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot




    listen 80;
    server_name somesite.com www.somesite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
    client_max_body_size 15M;



}
```

Comment: does it work locally in development?

Comment: did you set `DEBUG = True` on settings.py?

Comment: It doesnt work in development with DEBUG=True, now with false it should work but it doesnt.

Comment: you should include your nginx config in your question.

Comment: Nginx has decent learning curve I'm sure you can figure this out with good time.

Comment: I found in some other posts people have recomended this https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors but i have no idea how i would implement this into my setup.

Comment: @MikeKioulMikeKioulepoglou If you keep the 404.html file in your main `templates` directory, django will automatically serve that file for 404 errors. You don't need to configure anything like `handler404` etc.

Comment: @xyres tried it, didnt work.